# Brand new to TypeScript, trying to use Sequelize

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

I am brand new to TypeScript and I am trying to use Sequelize and Sequelize Auto to generate database models and then use those to make queries.

So far, the models have been generated, however when I try to actually use them, I get errors.

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */
// tslint:disable
import * as sequelize from 'sequelize';
import {DataTypes} from 'sequelize';
import {settings_user_tblInstance, settings_user_tblAttribute} from './db';

module.exports = function(sequelize: sequelize.Sequelize, DataTypes: DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define<settings_user_tblInstance, settings_user_tblAttribute>('settings_user_tbl', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'user_tbl',
        key: 'id'
      },
      unique: true
    },
    notification_email_enabled: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'settings_user_tbl'
  });
};
```

However when trying to use this model, I get the following errors:

```
   return sequelize.define<settings_user_tblInstance, settings_user_tblAttribute>('settings_user_tbl', {


src/models/tag_group_tbl.ts:7:70 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'DataTypes' as a type.

 module.exports = function(sequelize: sequelize.Sequelize, DataTypes: DataTypes) {
```

I am pretty lost on both of these errors - it appears like DataTypes is defined correctly? And this is the way that Sequelize Auto generated the file - did it do so incorrectly?

And why is it expecting only 0 arguments instead of 2?

Could this maybe be a version incompatibility thing?

Sorry for the pretty clueless question - I've literally JUST started working with TypeScript and I'm not totally sure what's going on here.

Comment: Hello @Cecil, were you able to test the fork in my answer, to see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: I’m testing today

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark the answer as resolved and award the bounty if it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Someone had the exact same [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/384) with the `sequelize-auto` repo and ended up [forking](https://github.com/realvariabledas/sequelize-auto) the repo, he seems to be really active lately: it worth a try of his version to see if it fixes the problem, he actually closed the issue in the original repo

But I would suggest you to try switching to [Typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) and [Typeorm-model-generator](https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator) because it was Typescript oriented from day one.

Comment: Damn it, I was out shopping for Xmas and my bounty expired. If your solution works for me, I'll start a new bounty and award it to you. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ok let me know :)

Comment: Well I guess it didn't work out for you... Happy New year anyway!

Comment: I haven’t had the time to test yet, I’ve been out of state. I’ll be testing in the next few days

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, TS support of `sequelize-auto` currently is really not good, the generator will create erroneous types.

Also last version has been published [two years ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto) and people forked and released [their own packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sequelize-auto), so I am not sure, if it is actively being worked on at all. You can still let `sequelize-auto` create the boilerplate column definitions, class attributes etc. and copy these into your models manually (later on).

First, run `sequelize-auto` with [`-z`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto#typescript) option to create type definitions. Example:

```
npx sequelize-auto -h localhost -u dontcare -d my-db.db --dialect sqlite -z
```

Given a `user` table in the database, `sequelize-auto` generates a file `user.ts` and other files under `models`, with a bunch of TS compile errors you already encountered.
For example `DataTypes` is a namespace, but used as a type in the function argument,  generics are set on the `sequelize.define` function, where no generics are expected at all.

Also `sequelize-auto` creates model definitions with [`sequelize.define`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html#usage-of--code-sequelize-define--code-). I would rather stick to class syntax, as shown in the first part of sequelize [TypeScript docs section](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html) - it produces more readable and easier to declare types.

So, all in all it makes more sense to stick to [above tutorial](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html), copy over the code we need, and delete the generated files afterwards again. Useful code is the generated table column definitions and class attributes:

In `user.ts` copy all table column attributes like `id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true, primaryKey: true }` etc. . Under `db.d.ts`, there should be something like a `userAttribute` interface, from which class attributes can be used. At last, create your models via class syntax somewhere:

```
import { Sequelize, Model } from 'sequelize';

// your models 
class User extends Model {
  // paste class attributes here
  // also add `null assertion` `!`, which is required in strict mode (see their docs)
}
...
```

and [initialize](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-init) the models. Here you can also paste the generated code in:

```
User.init({ /*pass column definitions*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/384#issuecomment-573530878) mentioned on [@Gomino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59402607/8839059), in January a new alternative was posted:

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = function(sequelize: Sequelize, _DataTypes: typeof DataTypes) {
  // return sequelize.define() ...
}
```

You can set any name instead of _DataTypes, but if you try to use "DataTypes", you will see the following message:

> 'DataTypes' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.ts(2502)

As an alternative, you can rename the import:

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes as DataType } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = function(sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: typeof DataType) {
  // return sequelize.define() ...
}
```

Or

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

type DataType = typeof DataTypes;
module.exports = function(sequelize: Sequelize, DataTypes: DataType) {
  // return sequelize.define() ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the right way to go about using Typescript in sequelize. Usually we define an interface of a model we want to define.

There's actually an example of a typescript implementation in the docs. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Comment: It could be good to specifically show them the "right way" to do in line the link the documentation you provided.

Comment: So I mean, these models were generated by Sequelize Auto - should I just not use that library? I assumed it was a fairly standard implementation